# Error inflating class android.appcombat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I keep getting "App has stopped working" error in the android studios emulator, these are the errors I am getting:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

The following is a portion of my activity_main.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The following is MainActivity.java file. Just a quick note, one of the errors shown was highlighted in blue and when I clicked it, it led to the "binding = ActivityMainbinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());" line of the following code:

```
package com.example.utatrivia;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.utatrivia.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(new CategoryModel("","History",""));
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categories);
        binding.categoryList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        binding.categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The full stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.utatrivia, PID: 13088
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.utatrivia/com.example.utatrivia.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.utatrivia:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.example.utatrivia.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:101)
        at com.example.utatrivia.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:95)
        at com.example.utatrivia.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8054)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8034)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1341)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040007 a=-1}
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:783)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5805)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:698)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:236)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:232)
            ... 28 more
```

Please let me know if any other files need to be uploaded.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Almost every "Error inflating" stack trace the real error is at the end, and this is just a propagated error.

Comment: @GabeSechan posted now

Comment: One of your parameters to the toolbar is invalid.  Something expecting a size.  Most likely android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  Try hardcoding it and see if it fixes that.  If so, your problem is that value.  Check any theme overrides you have, and for spelling mistakes.

Comment: @amaanm01 Can you try removing minHeight and theme and see if the issue gets fixed or still persists?
If it fixes the issue then try to hardcode the value or use a direct reference instead of ?attr.

Comment: @GabeSechan Could you please tell me how to hardcode minHeight? And also theme

Comment: @SurenderKumar how can I hardcode the values for minHeight and theme?

Comment: Set it to a known value.  Like 75 dp.  But from removing it below, it seems you have other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing minHeight then It should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doing that gave the following error: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using data binding but you are not converted your XML file into data binding.
you should wrap your parent layout into a **layout** tag to use data binding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in your java file there is also one change.

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main,null);
```

Comment: Using the layout tag gave following error: Wrong closing tag name

Comment: @Gabe Sechan who ?

Comment: @amaanm01 you have to enable dataBinding first in the app level gradle file, after that you put your XML code into it and try again.

Comment: @amaanm01       buildFeatures {        
                                 dataBinding true
                            }.    put this in app level gradel file.

Comment: The OP.  Enabling databinding won't help, he's not actually using it.  His main problem is his theme isn't defining a variable correctly.  His secondary problem is his theme has an incorrect base theme.  There may be a tertiary problem beyond that, but none of his code has to do with databinding, and enabling it won't help him.  What he does seem to be trying is to use ViewBinding.  Which is totally different and your suggestion wouldn't help with.